# tabview with fragments in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Hi I am creating tabview by extending fragments in one of my tab i have a button when I click that I need to move to another screen but in same tab it is displaying next screen but along with the previous screen what should I do so that I can view only one screen in the tab this is my code below

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment  {

    LinearLayout mLayout;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container == null) {         
                 return null;
        }
        LinearLayout theLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container, false);
     // Register for the Button.OnClick event

    Button b = (Button)theLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        void onContentChanged () {}

                @Override       
        public void onClick(View v) {

               Fragment mFragment = new third_fragment_view();
                       android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(R.id.container, mFragment);
               ft.addToBackStack(null);
               ft.commit();
               //ft.add(R.id.container, mFragment);     
        }
    });
    return theLayout;       
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code google posted for handling fragment tab activities?  It works very well:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Comment: i have tried but it is giving error as Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yor.packae.namespace/yor.packae.namespace.FragmentTabs}: java.lang.ClassCastException: FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: and i have adoubt in this line  mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null); here FragmentStackSupport is the package name in which CountingFragment.class is defined?

Comment: The code goes in your FragmentActivity.  The "mTabManager.addTab...simple" "simple" needs to be replaced with the fragment you are trying to display.   The error looks like you haven't got the compatability package installed

Comment: hi in my tab for navigating from one screen to another shall i need to call onTabChange() ?